# I Have PHP Script With Bad Responce?

Tags: php

My script is:

```
$arr=array('A','B');
foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val=str_replace(array('B'),array('C'),substr($val,0,1));
}
print_r($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)echo $key.'=>'.$val.'|||||';
echo phpversion();
```

When i run it responce look like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => C
)
0=>A|||||1=>A|||||5.6.16
```

I think responce must be as 0=>A|||||1=>C||||| but it is not. I can't find reason. Is this a PHP bug or is my script needs a fix?

Comment: change the `$val` to `$value` or whatever since both the `$val` is in the same scope, the second `$val` will be refer to the first `$val`, example : https://3v4l.org/p9sFQ

Comment: But this seems like a bug; doesn't it?